# Cashable copy of a check

Tags: check, deposits, atm

what does it mean when BOA sends you a cashable copy of a check deposited in an ATM that was not endorsed

Comment: Can you edit the question to make the details clear? The check was from you, or to you? As written, it's tough to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the original check that was deposited in the ATM is shredded or otherwise unrecoverable. The bank does have an image of it, so they have issued you a valid copy so that you can re-deposit it.